# How to save project as web application in Structr

Tags: structr

How to export website and publish under my domain name and accessible from the web. Also, if the answer is: Structr is an engine, then how to remove port numbers from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need a running Structr instance on your server with ports 80 (and 443 in case of HTTPS) configured. Then let your DNS A record point to your server's IP address.

The easiest way to get Structr up and running on an internet host is via Docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/structr/structr/

With Docker, you can also define the port mapping, see https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/. Make sure no other process (Apache etc.) uses the ports.

To export/import a Structr app, follow this article: https://support.structr.com/article/428